# can i send button click request from js to php

Tags: php, reactjs

## Demo Code i need to tiger from my react button instead

This code is in a PHP demo file i acquired, i created my own react version of the files but i am not sure how to go about executing this line from my react button.
i want to start the registration process from my own react button. is this possible.

```
<?php 
      echo $register = "<a href='finspot:FingerspotReg;$url_register' class='btn btn-xs btn-primary' 
      onclick=\"user_register('nick','nick')\">Register</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

`button click` is a front-end operation.

PHP deals only with back-end

If you want to simulate a `click`, this needs to be done via JS/React, which can in turn send a HTTP GET/POST request towards PHP

Comment: yes but would it be possible to add that code to the variable $register without the button properties and just echo it when i post my data to the page so it just picks up the post and automatically executes the function.

Comment: You could `echo` out with PHP, but that will not automatically execute on it's own. Once `echoed`, then the front end can trigger and check, and evaluate this code, and go further.

Comment: To execute a `click trigger` , you need html/JS/React = front-end. That click can be picked up either by GET/POST request and be sent to the back-end (PHP) and worked there, and return some answer, or that click can be picked up by frontend (JS) and do something else that might or might not need to be sent to any backend.. From your question there are not enough details on what your goal is exactly, and not much to work with, that is why I tried to clarify what is where... If you provide more details, or goal, or actual error, so we get a better sense, maybe we could provide a better answer.

Comment: the thing is i have this fingerprint scanner i am trying to implement but the demo is in php so i am trying to integrate with my react project.

Comment: the button code i provided it launches a software which waits for a fingerprint to be scanned and sends that data to the url_register while the onclick method keeps track of the proceed i am trying to launch the software from my react front end and send the data to my php back end for processing.

Comment: i will do some more research and try to better explain what i am trying to accomplish

Comment: ok, so the `onclick method` can keep track of the process from the frontend, but React/JS at that time, can still be sending `(a)sync` requests to the backend with newly received data, which can be processed and returned with a promise to the frontend JS, which in turn will receive new information from the backend and decide what to do next. I think this should be the flow you need to follow from what you've explained.

Comment: the only data that i will send from react is the username. can i email you i was notified this discussion is too long. rickal.hamilton@gmail.com

Comment: well i guess there is no other choice i will have to create the entire registration form with php.